# Does JBoss run well on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, jboss

It appears that we will have to build/deploy one of our new JBoss apps on Windows.

All our current deployments are on Solaris so we were slightly concerned with the stability of this model.  Apparently half of JBoss deployments are on Windows if this [article](http://radar.oreilly.com/2005/11/jboss-on-windows.html) is accurate.  But I was wondering what the community had to say..  Is Windows considered a solid platform to deploy JBoss on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be fine. The JBoss folks have paid careful attention to how their software behaves on Windows, even [working with Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2005/sep05/09-27MSJBossInteropPR.mspx) on it. Make sure you look at [the up to date recommendations for running JBoss on Windows](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/RunJBossAsAServiceOnWIndows). There are multiple ways to set it up and some are no longer recommended. If you just google it, you'll likely find instructions for the outdated setup.

Answer (score 2):

For development I run JBoss on a Windows platform and it runs without any problems.

One pitfall I tapped in was the different sorting behaviour of the file systems. I had two jar files that happened to contain different versions of the same class. On a Linux system one jar was loaded first, on Windows the other, resulting in strange errors. But of course, you should never have two versions of the same class at one time, so this happens only in a badly configured system.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS is tested for server editions of Windows - 2003, 2008 etc.
Also, some JBoss AS developers develop on Windows, some on Macs.

See [the list of tested JBoss EAP configurations](https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663).

Yes, JBoss AS should run well on Windows.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think it did provide an answer. If it's tested on some platform, then I guess that implies that it will run on it. However adding that explicitely.